# How to define a web3 contract type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type of web3 contract with typescript. We know that a web3 contract is defined in the form that:

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)
```

My question is how to define a type of such contract so that the following code is possible:

```
function myFunction(someContract: contract){...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you don't have web3.js:

```
npm i web3
```

To get the type, paste this in imports:

```
import { Contract } from "web3-eth-contract"
```

Now you can use Contract as a type

```
function myFunction(someContract: Contract) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Install this:

   ```
   npm i web3-eth-contract.
   ```
2. Import `Contract`:

   ```
   import { Contract } from "web3-eth-contract"
   ```
3. Use this `Contract` as a contract type:

   ```
   export const stake = async (masterChefContract:Contract, pid:number, 
   amount:number, account:string) => {
   return masterChefContract.methods
     .deposit(pid, new BigNumber(amount).times(new BigNumber(10).pow(18)).toString())
     .send({ from: account })
     .on('transactionHash', (tx) => {
       return tx.transactionHash
     })
   }
   ```